# Trying to separate table cells by date inputted from an alert textField. How could I look at doing that?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

in my app I have a tableView section that will allow the user to input a cell and then add a date. When the date is added, the cell is put into a section underneath the date. How could I look at doing this? I have tried to find solutions or people that have had similar problems but I couldn't find any. So for example, you create a cell with the name "Christmas" and set the date to the 25th December 2019, how could I take the date from the textField inside the UIAlertController and input it into a section header inside of my tableView.
Here is my alertController code:

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select a year for your memory", message: "Select a year so that your memories are sorted.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Add a year"
            textField.delegate = self

            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
            self.yearDates = textField.text
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
            let textField = alert?.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
            if textField?.text != ""{
                print("Text field: \(String(describing: textField?.text!))")
            }
        }))
   self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: you could store the text in a var and use that for section header title?

Comment: How would I look at saving the dates and then making sure that the corresponding table cells is properly sorted.

Comment: @Concon23a - you need to have some kind of data to fill the cells, probably an array of custom objects (which would contain the name and date). When the user taps "OK" you would use a protocol / delegate pattern to update your data, then reload the table (or at least a section).